# How can I write on a new Line in a MultiLine Textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have to make a program, where you're able to type in a minimum value and a maximum value. Then all the numbers from the min. to max. that are even should be showed in a multiline textbox.

But when the even number gets written into the textbox, it always overwrites the number which was written into the textbox before.

I tried Enviroment.NewLine and also this \r\n thing, but I probably used it wrong.

```
private void cmdstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); i++)
    {
        int a = i % 2;
        if (a == 0)
        {
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, its supposed to output all even numbers from the min. to max. in a multiline textbox. Each number should be on a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because you overwrite it each time.

Try the following code:

```
textBox3.Text += i.ToString()+Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! But could you explain to me, what exactly happens with this code? For example, why is there a += and not only a = anymore?

Comment: @ManuelSarica when you write `=` next value erases previous value.

Comment: when you write `+=` it takes previous value and append right part of the expression to it, it's equivalent to textbox3.Text=textbox3.Text+i.ToString()+Environment.NewLine

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. Why do i have to use i.ToString(), what does it do? I haven't created any string, so I don't quite understand what happens there yet.

Comment: @ManuelSarica all objects in C# have ToString method. Convert.ToString casts int to IConvertible interface and then call ToString. Take a look at source code:https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/int32.cs -> ToString and https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/convert.cs -> ToString

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set Multiline property to true on the textBox3.

You can set it through properties window after selecting textbox3 or you can write below line in the form constructor after initializeComponents is done.

```
textBox3.Multiline = true;
```

Once this is done, Environment.NewLine or **\r\n** both should work.

Comment: I have done that already, but as someone else pointed out, I always overwerote it. They both work now, I just used them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by yourself, if you write multiline text

Input:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7

to your textbox using designer and `Text` property, you can see that it generates something like this:

txt value:

> "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7"

Code:

```
string txt = multiLineTextBox.Text;
```

So if you add `\r\n` to your existing text, it will append text to new line:

```
for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text); i <= Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text); i++)
{
    int a = i % 2;
    if (a == 0)
    {
        textBox3.Text = $"{textBox3.Text}{i}\r\n";
        // or using string.Format for older versions
        //textBox3.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}\r\n", textBox3.Text, i);
    }
}
```